# SQL - Execute two update queries at one time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I am trying to allocate a value from one table into another table using an update script.

This works fine for one record with a matching possibility

```
UPDATE    Template_Survey
SET              K2ref = tbAsset.AssetNo
FROM         Template_Structure_Location INNER JOIN
                      Template_Survey ON 
                      Template_Structure_Location.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_LOCATION_REF = Template_Survey.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_LOCATION_REF INNER JOIN
                      tbAsset ON Template_Structure_Location.RoomID = tbAsset.LocationID AND Template_Structure_Location.RoomID = tbAsset.LocationID
WHERE     K2transferNote ='Reallocate - same no of spare items' and (tbAsset.AssetName = 'Archive or re-use') and (TEMPLATE_SURVEY_REF = 4369 or TEMPLATE_SURVEY_REF = 4405)
and (Template_Survey.K2ref = 0 OR
                      Template_Survey.K2ref IS NULL)
```

but if there are two records in Template_Survey table and in the tbAsset table that match the criteria, the first record found in the tbAsset table is used as the value against both records in the Template_Survey table.

When there is just one possible record I run a second query to update the tbAsset.AssetName value so that that record can no longer be found by the previous query eg

```
UPDATE tbAsset
SET tbAsset.AssetName = 'Reallocated to item in same location-needs update'
WHERE     (AssetNo IN
                      (SELECT     K2Ref
                        FROM         Template_Survey)) and  (tbAsset.AssetName = 'Archive or re-use')
```

How do I write something that will do the first query for one record and then the second query for the corresponding record before repeating the process so that a distinct record is found each time?

Thanks in advance. Sorry if it doesn't make much sense, it's really hard to explain.

Comment: In the case of multiple rows, is the tbAsset.AssetNo the same on each row?

Comment: Apologies for the delay responding. tbAsset.AssetNo is unique in the tbAsset table but is returned duplicated in the template_survey results.